# If my parent class throws an exception, must my child class catch it?

Tags: java, oop, exception, try-catch

I have a parent class which throws some exceptions, not handling those exceptions in the parent class. And now I am inheriting this parent class. Is it necessary to catch exceptions thrown by my parent class?

Answer (score 0):

You should catch all of your exceptions where they occur. Where you think that a code could throw an exception make a try-catch statement and handle the exception. you don't want to have exceptions and do not handle them.

Gotta catch 'em all!

Comment: It depends. If people use your API wrongly, sure, you should throw exceptions. They will know they did it wrong.

Comment: In that case yes. If you create an API and one parent method throw an exception then your child should catch and handle them

Comment: "You should catch all of your exceptions where they occur"... No, its not necessary.. Actually, most Enterprise level projects tend to throw exceptions to parent classes/common exception handling utils class.. This will prevent exception handling code being embedded in business logic.

Comment: That is right. It was my mistake, I worked to much on a project with Android and had to much troubles with exception handling that I didn't concentrate to the question

Answer (score 0):

Overridden methods can throw only the exceptions or the subclasses of expectations that is thrown by the parent method that it overrides

Answer (score 0):

If your parent class throws an Exception then your child class may either throw the exception or you can also catch the exception appropriately in the over-riding method.

Overridden methods can throw only the subclasses of exception thrown by the method in superclass, and it cannot throw the superclass of exception thrown by the method in superclass.